# Convert audio file to numbers array to visualizate it

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app where I want to play an audio file and visualize it, I didn't find a suitable package for it and decided to make it myself.

I made everything but audio visualization. To visualizate a file I need some kind of library that will analyze audio for me and return numbers array. I will use each number of the array as a point on my future graph.

Let's imagine I have this package, ideally I would like to use like this:

```
const audioPath = somePackage.analyzeAudio(audio.url);
console.log(audioPath);
// Output: [0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 8, 0]
```

In array **[0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 8, 0]** I will understand that at the beginning the audio has no sound at all then it's getting louder and at the end it's silent again. Later I can use these numbers to plot a graph.

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: It sounds like you are just trying to decode the audio file. Is there a reason a library like this doesn't meet your needs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-decode? If not, what exactly are you asking the library to analyze for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything useful to analyze an audio on client side so I decided to do it on server (nodejs) and then send parsed data to client.

I implemented it with help of this package => https://github.com/audiojs/web-audio-api.

This code helped me a lot => https://github.com/victordibia/beats/blob/master/beats.js